# How to implement continuous String loop

Tags: java, string, loops

I'm new to Java, got stuck with the following:

> Create a program that will output to console your names and where you are from. Make your program ask the user for this information.
>   **Advanced Assignment:** Change the program so that it runs in a continuous loop, asking the user for name and where they are from, and
>   outputting to the console. If the user types in "X" for either the
>   name or where they are from, terminate the loop.

I implemented the first part, but having trouble with advanced assignment. Can anyone please give me a hint, thank you!

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MainClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner myScan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter your name");
        String myName = myScan.next();
        System.out.println("Enter your location");
        String myLocation = myScan.next();
        System.out.println("Your name is "+ myName + " and your location is " + myLocation);
    }
}
```

Comment: Take a look to [`while`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/while.html) statement.

Comment: Did you try using google? [This](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_loop_control.htm) is the first result from googling "java loop".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would nest the contents of your main method in a continuous loop and then check the inputs for "X", If either is "X" then you would "break" out of the loop.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner myScan = new Scanner(System.in);
    while(true) {
        System.out.println("Enter your name");
        String myName = myScan.next();
        System.out.println("Enter your location");
        String myLocation = myScan.next();

        if(myName.equals("X") || myLocation.equals("X")){
            break;
        }

        System.out.println("Your name is " + myName + " and your location is " + myLocation);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MainClass {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner myScan = new Scanner(System.in);

    while(true){
        System.out.println("Enter your name");
        String myName = myScan.next();
        if(myName.equals("X"))
            break;
        System.out.println("Enter your location");
        String myLocation = myScan.next();
        if(myLocation.equals("X"))
            break;
        System.out.println("Your name is "+ myName + " and your location is " + myLocation);
    }
}
}
```